# android Bluetooth "Service discovery failed"

Tags: android, bluetooth

Although a lot has been written about this topic, I still cannot find the solution for my specific problem:

I am trying to connect a Sasmsung Galaxy SIII  with a simple Bluetooth device. When I pair these two using the phone's Bluetooth settings (no PIN required), it works. But if the device has not manually been paired before, I receive following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:462)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:240)
at com.concept.proiv.BluetoothConnection$1.run(BluetoothConnection.java:84)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Related code:

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) ...
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) ...

BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:0A:3A:2F:7C:1A");
try
{
    btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}
catch (IOException e) ... - WORKING
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
try
{
    btSocket.connect(); <-- FAILED HERE
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace(); //java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
}
```

Comment: How it usually works: Start discovery, if a device is found, initiate pairing (if not paired yet), if pairing is successful, connect to the device - done. Are you going through the pairing process in your code? I suggest you take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: I sure did read android docs, and also a lot of posts about this problem.

Comment: The only solution we found is to set a BT password on the device